# Can't avoid BeautifulSoup warning

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

In a python 2.7 script, I'm using BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_page_accueil_pluzz = "http://pluzz.francetv.fr/"
f = urllib.urlopen(url_page_accueil_pluzz)
page_accueil_pluzz = f.read()
f.close()
soup = str(BeautifulSoup(page_accueil_pluzz, "html.parser"))
root = fromstring(soup)
new_soup = (tostring(root, pretty_print=True).strip())
new_soup = BeautifulSoup(new_soup, "html.parser")
```

I can not avoid this message:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py:166: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

To get rid of this warning, change this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup])

to this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup], "html.parser")

  markup_type=markup_type))
```

I'm on Kubuntu 16.04 (x64)

python-bs4 version 4.4.1-1

Python v. 2.7.12

Adding "html.parser" seems no effect for my script. Someone has an idea?

```
$ cat dPluzz.py | grep "BeautifulSoup("
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_video, "html.parser")
soup = BeautifulSoup(self.page_pluzz, "html.parser")
soup = BeautifulSoup(self.feuille_canal, "html.parser")
soup = BeautifulSoup(self.sous_feuille_canal, "html.parser")
soup = str(BeautifulSoup(page_accueil_pluzz, "html.parser"))
new_soup = BeautifulSoup(new_soup, "html.parser")
```

Comment: Are you sure you are actually running what you think you are? I don't see how you get any warning if you have actually passed the parser. How are you running the code?

Comment: Ah ok.. I'm running the code with `python code.py` simply.. All my BeautifulSoup lines have this argument, `html.parser`. I don't understand

Comment: I have added another line (new_soup), I don't know wich line get the warning

Comment: Did you save your file after you made changes?

Comment: yep! But I see the second (new_soup) is xml...

Comment: What do you mean by *it is  is xml*?

Comment: No, sorry a mistake. It's html.

Comment: OK, I am 99.9 percent certain you are not running the script you think you are, what is the name of the script?

Comment: I can certify 100% the script is this one, I can print or not...

Comment: I have seen [this](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser), but all these packages are installed...

Comment: Run `cat your_script.py | grep "BeautifulSoup("
`

Comment: I have added the result in my question

Comment: Are you running this script by importing it into another by any chance?

Comment: No, it's a direct launch. If you want you can see my PPA page, the software is called [dpluzz](https://launchpad.net/~yoggic/+archive/ubuntu/dpluzz/+packages)

Comment: You are not using lxml anywhere either?

Comment: No, just html. Weird isn't it?

Comment: But what is `fromstring`? That is from lxml no? You are not using `from lxml.html import soupparser` anywhere?

Comment: Yes. In fact I have coded this 2 years ago, I don't remember... But after a try, `fromstring` is not essential. If I write new_soup = soup, the warning disapear, and it works.

Comment: So it is fixed or you still have the issue?

Comment: No, I think it's fixed ! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: No worries, you're welcome.